# Can Apache be used as a front end for Django and Tornado at the same time?

Tags: python, django, apache, tornado, wsgi

I have Apache set up as a front end for Django and it's working fine.  I also need to handle web sockets so I have Tornado running on port 8888.  Is it possible to have Apache be a front end for Tornado so I don't have to specify the 8888 port?

My current /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf file is:

```
    

        WSGIDaemonProcess myappiot python-path=/home/ubuntu/myappiot/sw/www/myappiot:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
        WSGIProcessGroup myappiot
        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ubuntu/myappiot/sw/www/myappiot/myappiot/wsgi.py


        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
```

Answer (score 1):

You can proxy the request. Checkout http://amir-x.com/apache-2-reverse-proxy-tornado for example.

Answer (score 1):

You would be better off to use nginx as a front end proxy on port 80 and have it proxy to both Apache/mod_wsgi and Tornado as backends on their own ports. Apache/mod_wsgi will actually benefit from this as well if everything is setup properly as nginx will isolate Apache from slow HTTP clients allowing Apache to perform better with fewer resources.